# Редактирование переменной Path из командной строки без прав администратора

Tags: cmd, администрирование, bat, path

Если максимально кратко суть вопроса, то команда `setx path "путь;%PATH%"` в командной строке без прав администратора работает неправильно. Требуется найти обходной путь или альтернативу этой команды, работающую без прав администратора.
Теперь подробно:

В общем, парочка приложений(в частности gcc компилятор) лежат на флешке, но для корректной работы требуется занести некоторые пути в переменную path. По задумке я должен вставить флешку в любой пк и одним открытием батника добавить все переменные куда надо и спокойно делать свои дела. Конечно, можно и [ручками всё сделать](https://superuser.com/questions/165909/how-can-i-set-user-environmental-variables-such-as-path-from-a-non-administrat), но так лучше.

В чем проблема: Известный факт, что переменные path есть *пользовательские* и *системные*.
Команда `setx path` редактирует *пользовательскую* переменную path, если добавить флаг `/M`, то можно редактировать *системную* переменную. В хелпе и на форумах обычно примеры типа такого `setx path "путь;%PATH%"`. По задумке код должен добавлять `путь;` в начало *пользовательской* переменной path. Это работает, если применять права администратора. А без прав переменная %PATH% - это каша из пользовательских и системных путей(не уничтожаются дубли). Т.е банально склеенные *пользовательские* и *системные* пути. Таким образом, при каждом применении такого участка кода в *пользовательскую* переменную path дополнительно вливаются *системные* переменные, которые, естественно, дублируются и быстро множатся.

немного экспериментов с переменной %PATH%:

Добавил в начало и конец *пользовательской* и *системной* переменных соответствующие значения и вывожу построчно(без прав администратора)

```bash
    C:\Users\TestW10>echo %path:;=&echo.%
    SystemBegin          <-- это часть системной переменной
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    SystemEnd            <-- и это       
    userBegin            <-- это часть пользовательской переменной
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    userEnd              <-- и это
```

Именно в таком порядке у меня и лежат переменные в графическом интерфейсе.

Теперь тоже самое, но с правами администратора:

```bash
    C:\Windows\system32>echo %path:;=&echo.%
    SystemBegin
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    SystemEnd
    userBegin
    userEnd
```

Становится ощущение, что %PATH% с правами администратора только убирает дубли, повторяющиеся в *пользовательской* переменной. Проверим еще. Добавил парочку дублирующихся переменных

```bash
    C:\Users\TestW10>echo %path:;=&echo.%
    SystemBegin
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    userEnd          <-- новая часть переменной внутри системной path
    SystemEnd
    userBegin
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    SystemEnd        <-- новая часть переменной внутри пользовательской path
    userEnd
```

Теперь тоже самое, но с правами администратора

```bash
    C:\Windows\system32>echo %path:;=&echo.%
    SystemBegin
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    userEnd     <-- 
    SystemEnd
    userBegin
```

В итоге userEnd  внутри *системной* переменной path появляется первым а userEnd внутри *пользовательской* переменной не дублируется. Аналогично для SystemEnd. Всё это подтверждает идею о том, что %PATH% с правами администратора выводит содержимое *системной* переменной path, после чего дополняет не дублирующимися значениями из *пользовательской* переменной path. В свою очередь %PATH% без прав администратора банально склеивает *системные* и *пользовательские* path, не разбирая дубли.

Проблема:
Естественно, команда `setx path "путь;%PATH%"` с разными значениями `%PATH%` ведет себя по разному. А именно, как и говорил выше, без прав администратора добавляет лишение значения, что при многократном использовании сразу засоряет переменную %PATH%. Каким образом, не имея прав администратора можно добиться правильной работы команды `setx path "путь;%PATH%"`?

Comment: `/m` пробовали?

Comment: Добится можно так: напишите скрипт который разбирает текущий `PATH`, удаляет в нём дупликаты. Проверяет, что новое значение там отсутствует. Если да, добавляет. Если нет, ничего не меняет.

Comment: Флаг /m работает только с правами администратора, да и в любом случае мне не нужно ничего добавлять в системный path. На счет скрипта, я написал подобный скрипт, но проблема не решена полностью. В итоге по факту в пользовательском path дублируются все системные path. В моих экспериментах выше уже и так всё дублировано, но на чистом пк такого не должно быть. Однако, даже с таким минусом уже можно жить